# Proof area triangle

Tags: proof-writing, triangles

$Let\enspace Z = a +ib,\enspace W = c + id\enspace \text{be points on the complex plane.}$

Show that the area of the triangle of vertices $0, Z, W$ is

$$\frac{1}{2}|Im(\overline{Z}W)|"$$

Hi, I'm having difficulties trying to show this.
Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Show us what you have done so far, so we can see where your difficulty is.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

$$\frac{\text{base}\times\text{height}}{2}$$

> [image]